# Angular way to wait for another asynchronous resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

Let's say in an Angular app, I have a controller which outputs a list of data, formatted according to configured rules. Both data should be fetched asynchronously:

- list config (for instance, which attributes to be displayed)
- data

Alright, since both data (config and data) are retrieved from a backend using $http/ngResource/Restangular, the code may look like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('ListCtrl', function (Backend) {
  var config,
      data;

  var draw = function() {
    Backend.getData(function(retrievedData) {
      // data retrieved asynchronously, store them:
      data = retrievedData;

      // to generate the list, we need both config and data:

      if (!config) {
        // <---- How can I wait until config has been loaded?
      }

      $scope.list = generateList(config, data);
  }

  // let's say, Backend.getConfig would make an asynch call and fetch the config data
  Backend.getConfig(function(retrievedConfig) {
    // config data retrieved asynchronously, store them:
    config= retrievedConfig;
  });
}
```

I hope you get the point: to generate the list and assign it to the scope, both input data is needed. But since the config does not change in the short run, I don't want to use $q.all() to wait for both. So, the config data should only be fetched the first time and then held in the controller (referenced by the variable "config"). This is implemented in the code above, but if somebody fires the 'draw()' function and the config is still loading, how can I make the code "wait" until the necessary config data has been fetched?

$emit/$broadcast come to my mind, but I don't like the idea because it feels like the wrong weapon for this target.

Are there other possibilities?

Comment: Use ` $q.all()` and cache `getConfig` call.

Comment: Identical to Nikos' answert below, thanks anyway, it hits the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap the `Backend.getConfig()` call with another service that executes the call only when needed and returns a promise. The other times, it returns a promise resolved with a cached value. E.g.:

```
.service("getCachedConfig", function(Backend, $q) {
    var cachedConfig;

    return function getCachedConfig(cb) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.promise.then(cb); // install the callback, to adhere to your API; I would consider using promises all the way...
        if( cachedConfig != null ) {
            deferred.resolve(cachedConfig);
        }
        else {
            Backend.getConfig(function(retrievedConfig) {
                cachedConfig = retrievedConfig;
                deferred.resolve(cachedConfig);
            });
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    };
})
```

Now you can do `$q.all(Backend.getPromiseForData(...), getCachedConfig())` (assuming the method `Backend.getPromiseForData` returns a promise). The config will be fetched only once. You can trivially enhance this to add a cache expiration.

Comment: Actually, I once had $q.all() for this, but wondered if there would be another solution. Seems like this is the way to go. Thanks for your input - I very much like the "cached value" idea and the hint to wrap it into a separate service! Thanks to dfsq also, for the same reason.